# 16*2 LCD on nodeMCU

Tags: lcd

I am getting this error while uploading a simple LCD program on NodeMCU can anyone guide me??........

```
esptool.py v2.8
Serial port COM9
Connecting........_____....._____....._____....._____....._____....._____.....____Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP-DeViL\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.6.3/tools/upload.py", line 65, in <module>
    esptool.main(cmdline)
  File "C:/Users/HP-DeViL/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.6.3/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 2890, in main
    esp.connect(args.before)
  File "C:/Users/HP-DeViL/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.6.3/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 483, in connect
    raise FatalError('Failed to connect to %s: %s' % (self.CHIP_NAME, last_error))
esptool.FatalError: Failed to connect to ESP8266: Timed out waiting for packet header
esptool.FatalError: Failed to connect to ESP8266: Timed out waiting for packet header
```

Comment: how is the LCD wired to the NodeMCU?

Comment: without i2c connector..... LiquidCrystal lcd(D1, D0, D5, D6, D7, D8); // Creates an LC object. Parameters: (rs, enable, d4, d5, d6, d7)

Comment: use some other pin instead of D8. it is io 15 a boot config pin and must be LOW at boot. or try to swap it to other pin of the LCD

Comment: Maybe just disconnect the NodeMCU from the display before flashing the software.

Answer (score -1):

I have seen this behavior on esp chips as well.  This happens when you've uploaded a program that utilizes the processor very heavily or a blank program.  I've gotten it to upload by unplugging and re-plugging, trying to time it correct so that it's just booting up while the programming begins.  Just keep trying this and eventually it should get through.